# React Native - Linking - Open FB page in FB App in Iphone

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I am using react native linking API to open an FB page.

It is working fine and navigates to the said page on Android but it only opens the FB app on iOS and does not go to the FB page.

Do you know why and what should be done to solve it ?

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found one way to open Facebook

```
Linking.openURL('https://www.facebook.com/n/?YOUR_PAGE_NAME');
```

Facebook wouldn't work if you remove "www"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.

here's a format for the urls :

```
fbApp: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'fb://profile/139996222323553360774' : 'fb://page/139996232323232553360774/',
```